# Inserting parameters into Oracle database through asp.net

Tags: asp.net, oracle, stored-procedures

I am developing an ASP.net application with Oracle database. When I try to insert data into table REGISTER, it throws an exception as below

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'INSERTREGISTER'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

table **REGISTER** has USERNAME, PASSWORD, EMAIL as columns

Store procedure INSERTREGISTER is as following

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE INSERTREGISTER IS

u1 varchar2(20);
p1 varchar2(20);
e1 varchar2(20);

BEGIN

INSERT INTO REGISTER (USERNAME, PASSWORD, EMAIL) VALUES (u1, p1, e1);

END INSERTREGISTER;
```

**my c# code is:**

```
public int Insert(string u1, string p1, string e1)

    {
        try
        {
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("INSERTREGISTER", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("u1", OracleType.VarChar)).Value = u1;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p1", OracleType.VarChar)).Value = p1;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("e1", OracleType.VarChar)).Value = e1;

            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
```

Kindly help me

regards,
Arjun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your procedure to

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE INSERTREGISTER (u1 varchar2,p1 varchar2,e1 varchar2) AS
BEGIN
--your sql statement
END
```

Comment: no need for the length of varchar2 `(20)`, just: `PROCEDURE INSERTREGISTER (u1 varchar2,p1 varchar2,e1 varchar2) AS
BEGIN ...`

Comment: @A.B.Cade: Thank you!!!!!! Errors gone but the data is getting inserted twice in the table.

Comment: That's because you're running `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` twice- one as a call and one in the `return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: @A.B.Cade : what should I add in the return statement?

Comment: @ArjunBabu- You can leave it as it is, but then remove the first call: `conn.Open();
 return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` . BTW you do have a conn.close() in a `finally` scope, right ?